# Errors happening in only PageSpeedInsight Test

Tags: reactjs, next.js13, pagespeed-insights

I am getting some errors in the page speed insights report but there are no errors in any browsers like Chrome, Edge, Safari and Firefox. I am not able to resolve that cause it is only happening to the headless Chromium browser which is used for page speed insight test.

I have also tried to get similar errors in the lighthouse but there are no errors and the performance was totally different from the page speed insight test. I have also tried some different tools to test the website like GTMatrix and WebPageTest I never faced any issues with them.

URL- https://stage.accuride.com/en-us

Error while running the test -
[image]

For Desktop the results are quite different from the lighthouse and Pagespeedinsight can anyone help me with this also?

[image]